# Solr Is it possible to remove the prefix/suffix of a dynamic field after adding it?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I have users asking to add dynamic fields to index after the index has been filled. At the moment I'm using solrj to add them.

```
    SolrInputDocument solrDoc = new SolrInputDocument();
    solrDoc.setField("id",myId);
    solrDoc.setField("model_txt", "test123");
    solr.add(solrDoc);
    solr.commit();
```

The field model get's added.

But when users try to search it with dismax they have to use

model_txt:test123

in stead of:

model:test123

I know solr needs the prefix/suffix to determine the fieldtype but is there a way to remove this after the field got added? Or another way to achieve the same result?

Edit:

The reason I was asking this is because the user can create new dynamic fields but he doesn't know about the type.

So if he adds model as a new dynamic field he doesn't know that it is model_txt in the index.

I know I should avoid users having to type fieldnames but when they want to dynamically add them there's no other way to do so?

Comment: Generally speaking, when we expose some subset of the Solr query syntax to end users (assuming non-technical-ish -- that of course drives everything), we always would manually finesse the queries and take care of things like field normalization, allowing you to have multiple fields (say for faceting, different tokenization, etc.) and just "do the right thing" for the user without them ever knowing it...

Comment: Hmmm k , so you suggest I would  check if the field needs the _txt? How can I do this?K, I tought after the first value was added the type was known to solr and it could remove _txt from the field value. I'll try it the way you suggest.

Comment: Why do you use field names in a dismax query? Define them in solrconfig.xml and users don't have to use any fieldnames at all.

Comment: I tought adding a fieldname:value improved the search

Comment: @O.Klein Is it possible to add a field to solrconfig while solr is running? Then I would change the search handler at runtime?

Comment: You can add the fields to qf parameter at runtime.

Comment: Yes true,I think I'll do it this way. But this does require me to save data outside of my application.